# how to SSH from local----> jump box ----> private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

work flow

part 1

ssh from local to --->my jump box is in the public subnet

part 2

I need the same users to ssh into the private subnet ec2 instances.

part 1 is working, I'm able ssh into jump box but I cant ssh from jump box user to private subnet ec2, able to ping the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second jump requires the keypair to be provided.

It is considered bad for security to store a keypair on a Jump box.

Instead, use **Agent Forwarding**. The method varies depending upon the operating system you are using.

See: [An Illustrated Guide to SSH Agent Forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html)